# Not able to remove Import button from Contact list view in lightning

Tags: lightning, permissions, list-view, import, custom-profile

I have deselected the "Import Personal Contacts / Import personal accounts and contacts" under "App Permissions" section on the custom Profile. But still list view shows "Import" button.

How can I remove import button on Contact.

Answer (score 1):

I removed all import permissions from profile and then Import button disappeared. And then I gave access to all import permissions except Import Personal contacts.It worked that way for me.